# Use yq to add a new root

Tags: yaml, yq

I am trying to add a new root to an existing yaml.

I have a values.yaml file with the following content

```
key1: value1
key2: value2
key3:
  key31: value31
  key32: value32
```

And I am trying to add a root to the existing yaml.

```
mainkey: 
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
  key3:
    key31: value31
    key32: value32
```

I tried yq with `+`, `merge` and nothing yielded the result i wanted. Is it possible to append a root to an existing yaml?

Comment: `yq '{"mainkey": .}' values.yaml` works with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), `yq -y '{mainkey: .} values.yaml` works with [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq).

Comment: thanks that works. i was trying it always the other way round  :-)